# Vertical layout to fill window with stretched middle component

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to do a single column vertical layout which fills the entire window. There are three components to this layout:

- header (constant, but unknown size)
- body (variable size, stretches to fill)
- footer (constant, but unknown size)

I've done the layout before where the header/footer are fixed and known sizes, but I'd like them to have a dynamic size now (based on the content). The flexible box model seems like it is intended to make this easy, but I can't figure out how to make it work (which may perhaps be due to browser support).

I need a solution only for FireFox at this time, and the absolute newest version would be okay (say 18 or 19).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>Header/Footer Vertical Centering Test</title>
      <style type="text/css">
      /* Set document height*/
      html, body { height:100%; }

      /* Set container height and context */ 
      #container { position:relative; min-height:100%; }

      /* Declare positioned children of container */
      #masthead, #footer { position:absolute; }

      /* Position masthead */
      #masthead { top:10px; }

      /* Position and layer footer */
      #footer { bottom:0; z-index: 2; }

      /* Set fluid height for footer */
      #footer { height:5%; }

      /* Set padding for content header placeholder */
      #header { padding-bottom: 10%; }

      /* Set fluid height and display for middle container */
      #middle { height:60%; display:table; padding-bottom: 5%; }

      /* Set display and vertically centered content */
      #vertcenter { display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
      </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="container">
      <div id="header"></div>

      <div id="middle">
        <div id="vertcenter">
            Content
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="masthead">
      header
      </div>

      <div id="footer">
      footer
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```